# Convert ePub to PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, epub

I am new to the iOS development and am developing document based iPad appliactio. So,
Is there any way to convert the epub document to pdf document in iOS. Please let me know.

Thanks 
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't think that iOS have some tools to do that. Best choice will be upload your document to some unix server and then convert it with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) for instance. But be aware that this type of conversion is poor quality fo 99% of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Seconding pandoc (for which you'll want an OS X, Linux, or Windows system), though I'm here looking for the solution.

Some tips though:

- An EPUB document is a structured format contained within a ZIP file.  Unpack that and you'll get the document in HTML format, plus images, plus structure information.
- Pandoc is a *very* nifty converter that will take single documents and convert between many, many file formats, including markdown, HTML, LaTeX, PDF, and ePub.  It won't read *from* ePub natively, though it seems to me that if you can parse the `package.opf` file you should be able to reconstruct the document in the form you prefer.

My general thought is to create LaTeX source from the HTML documents, and use that to produce PDF (or other) outputs.  I'm seeking tips on simplifying and automating this, will follow up if I find more.